# Google maps never display in IE8

Tags: google-maps

I've used Google map in my asp.net application. It shows empty space in IE8 where Google map is placed, it works fine in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Could be either a Javascript or a CSS issue. Hard to tell without any code examples, so please post some examples if you can.

Comment: Google maps work fine in IE8, see if you've got JavaScript errors. Press F12 in IE8 for more help.

Comment: Posting code would be good; better yet post a URL.